# Book about interplanetary travel, perfume mixing, and telepathy

Tags: story-identification, telepathy

Read this book in the early 90s. The protagonist goes to another planet and there is a lot to do with perfume. Correctly mixing perfumes to some important end. The population is telepathic, and I remember the perfumes having a role in blocking the telepathy and him taking great care to guard his thoughts closely.

Definitely not [Crompton Divided](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/668663.Crompton_Divided).

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? When did you read it, for example? If so you can [edit] your question to include extra detail.

Comment: What aspects of *Crompton Divided* don't match up? I'm asking, in part, because people are going to immediately jump on that one because it matches your listed aspects. :) And saying why a work is not the correct answer is a good way to get more details.

Comment: By perfume, could you mean the mixing of scents as a means of entertainment at a table?

Comment: If not for the mention of the population being telepathic, I would have guessed you were remembering *Silence is Deadly* by Lloyd Biggle, Jr. In that one, series hero Jan Darzek goes undercover on a world where the humanoid-looking aliens are all deaf, but have highly developed senses of smell. Disguising himself as a perfumer, surrounded by the strong scents of perfumes, is the only way to protect himself from being detected as smelling "all wrong." But nobody was telepathic in that one.

Comment: Lorendiac, thank you for the suggestion.   I just purchased the kindle version and will take a look this evening.  It sounds very close, but I really have a strong recollection of the telepathy angle...

Comment: @MaxsonSmith Just wondering how it went with *Silence is Deadly.* Did it look familiar, or was the resemblance to the story you described purely coincidental?